# Почему не отображается FMX.TPath?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Познакомился с `FMX.TPath` - разместил на форме, скормил данные из svg
В визуальном редакторе рисунок отображается, а при запуске в самой программе пропадает.

Может есть какая-то команда "распечатки"?
Кода нет - я тупо разместил и тупо ввел данные и все.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, таки ...Canvas.DrawPath отлично справляется